# How to create a new attribute in a dataframe based on duplicate words in a string, in corresponding row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have the data-frame having Google Play application names, single name in each row. I want to create a new column in front of the application name, if the name string has duplicate words in it, new column will have 1, otherwise 0.

For example, if a app name is "Free Calls: make international Calls", so "calls" would be duplicate.

Secondly, a new column having the count of duplicate words based on name string.

Following is the code, I cant figure out how create a column out of in-front of app name.

```
count = 0
duplicate = False
for name in df['App Name']:
name.lower()
nameWords = []
traversedWords = []   
    nameWords = name.split()
    for word in nameWords:
        if word in traversedWords:
            count += 1
        elif word not in traversedWords:
            traversedWords.append(word)

if count > 0:
    duplicate = True
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Please post a sample of your dataframe, as well as what you want the output to be in addition to what you've tried already so we can help!

Comment: I added the code, what I have been trying to work. but cant figure it out.

Comment: Duplicate as in, the word's occurred before in some other app name, or duplicate word in the same app name?

Comment: @SafwanSamsudeen, Not before, in single string (name). For example, if a app name is "Free Calls: make international Calls", so "calls" would be duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```py
df['is_duplicate'] = [sorted(set(x.split())) != sorted(x.split()) for x in df['App Name']]
```

Let's break it up:

```py
[... for x in df['App Name']]
```

Iterate over the app name column

```py
sorted(set(x.split())) != sorted(x.split())
```

Check if any of the split words' count is more than one. This is done through checking whether a sorted set of the split sentence (a set removes duplicates) is the same as the split sentence itself. If it is, then it's not a duplicated word sentence, if it isn't, then that means the `set` constructor removed some duplicates, and the sentence has duplicated words.

Comment: That works great, thanks.  Could you please also point out how to modify your provided code to get count of matches?

Comment: Count of matches? You mean the number of words duplicated, or the number of a times a word was duplicated?